# FIR Filter implementation vs Linear convolution implementation

Tags: convolution, finite-impulse-response, c

I came across a C code for the FIR filter on one of the websites. It is as follows

```
 void fir(short * y, const short *x, const short *h, int n_out, int n_coefs)
 {
      int n;
      for (n = 0; n < n_out; n++)
      {
          int k, sum = 0;
          for(k = 0; k < n_coefs; k++)
          {
              sum += h[k] * x[n - n_coefs + 1 + k];
          }
          y[n] = sum;
      }
  }
```

I used the following input in my main function. Considered n_coeffs as 4 and n_out as 7 (4+4-1). And the coefficients are as follows (after padding)

x ={1,2,3,4,0,0,0};
h={1,2,3,4,0,0,0};

And then, I modified the above FIR code as follows and used it in my function

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    y[i] = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
            y[i] = y[i] + h[j] * x[i - 4 + 1 + j];
    }
}
```

And the obtained output is {4,11,20,30,20,11,4}

But when I perform convolution operation,

```
 for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 {
    y[i] = 0;

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        y[i] = y[i] + h[j] * x [i-j];
    }
  }
```

The obtained output is {1,4,10,20,25,24,16}.

Ideally, both convolution and FIR Filter should give the same output, right?

And one more thing I observed is the output will be {4,11,20,30,20,11,4} when the h coefficients are time-reversed before padding i.e. when h={4,3,2,1,0,0,0}.

I am confused a bit, where I am going wrong?

Comment: In your second code snippet the index to the array `x[]` is `i-4+1+j`. Now, as an example, if `i=0` and `j=0` (which will happen), what will the resulting index be then? Ask yourself if this makes sense. Then ask yourself if this whole question makes any sense.

Comment: @MattL. All the negative indexed values are getting replaced with 0. I verified it too. It is as expected, right?

Comment: No, you can't count on that, you have to make that sure in your code.

Comment: @MattL.  Yes. I verified by printing every value of x. All the negative indexed values of x are 0.

Comment: OK, but how does that guarantee anything? By addressing out-of-range values of an array you're just hoping to be lucky. The result can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: @MattL. That's true. I understood your point. But let's assume that the compiler is doing the work of replacing the invalid values with zero's every time. Now, in this case, why do outputs are not matching? I would like to know are there any other issues?

Comment: @RamakrishnaChaitanyaRachumal Namasthay, `y[i] = y[i] + h[j] * x[i - 4 + 1 + j];` if `i = 0` and `j = 0` then `x[-3]` ? Presumably you are bit lucky to see some sane values instead of garbage for `x[-3]`

Comment: @RamakrishnaChaitanyaRachumal Even if the compiler is nice to you, you have to perform the linear convolution in correct way as described in the text.

Comment: @RamakrishnaChaitanyaRachumal Nevertheless, I will give you welcome points.

Comment: @jomegaA ...I implemented FIR filtering as described in the text. And also, I believe there is no problem in the code written for linear convolution (2nd code)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the code is written in such a way that it gives a correct output only when the coefficients are passed in the reverse fashion. Comparatively, the code will be simpler if we pass the coefficients in reverse fashion.